# Create table in Mysql dynamically with PHP,ajax,jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to create a table in MySQL dynamically from PHP.

User inputs should be inserted into that table using jQuery,AJAX and PHP.

my code is looking like this.

```
var toServer = brandname+','+prodname+','+qty;
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'sample.php',
data: toServer,
cache: false,
success: function(res){
alert(res);
},
error: function(){
alert(1);
}
})
```

In sample.php:

```
require '../models/orderClass.php';
$order = new orderClass;
$data = explode(',',$_REQUEST['toServer']);
$res = $order->addToCart('mymail@domain.com', $data[0], $data[1],$data[2]);
echo $res;
```

In orderClass:

```
$this->con = new mysqli('servername','user','pass','dbnaem');
if($this->con->connect_error)
{
echo($this->con->connect_error);
}
```

Without AJAX, its working. After adding $.ajax() its not working.
Please help me out
Thanks in advance

I am new to AJAX and I added error: function at last since it was not working.

Comment: I think your data parameter is wrong should be used like  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the "data: " sent to server in $_REQUEST so it must be a hash of data.
try this:

```
var toServer = brandname+','+prodname+','+qty;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'sample.php',
    data: {'toServer': toServer},
    cache: false,
    success: function(res){
        alert(res);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert(1);
    }
})
```

or another version:
javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'sample.php',
    data: {
        'brandname': brandname,
        'prodname': prodname,
        'qty': qty
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(res){
        alert(res);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert(1);
    }
});
```

php part:

```
require '../models/orderClass.php';
$order = new orderClass;
$brandname = $_REQUEST['brandname'];
$prodname = $_REQUEST['prodname'];
$qty = (int)$_REQUEST['qty'];
$res = $order->addToCart('mymail@domain.com', $brandname, $prodname, $qty);
echo $res;
```

Comment: nice! happy to help (:

Answer (score 0):

your variable should b like this

```
var toServer = "brandname="+brandname+" &prodname= "+prodname+" &qty="+qty;
```

and in `sample.php`

use like this

```
$brandname =  $_REQUEST['brandname'];

$prodname=  $_REQUEST['prodname'];

$qty=  $_REQUEST['qty'];
```